# How to refresh DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables plugin to make my table interactive.

The table is echo'd by PHP on the page.

When I add a record to the DB I am loading the table using jQuery load() but this breaks DataTables.

How can I update the table while still keeping DataTables Intact?

Note: I am using DOM as the data source and not server side processing.

Comment: Can you post the javascript code you are using to set up datatables please?

Comment: $('#new').dataTable({
   "iDisplayLength": 5,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
  });

Comment: I am usin this to create my table 'var lol = $('#new').dataTable({
"iDisplayLength": 5,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"bDestroy": true});'

then this in my another function   lol.fnDestroy();
    lol = null;
    $("#p").load("table.php");
    $lol = $('#new').dataTable({
     "iDisplayLength": 5,
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "bDestroy": true
    }); but it still doesn't work

Comment: answer is dependent on what you are loading...whole table refresh or just rows when you update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If doing a complete reload of the whole table, wrap your initial datatables initialization code in a function. Call that function on page load. When replacing the table completely with ajax you likely should remove the table parent div that is created by plugin as a wrapper for all the non table DOm elements it creates. If table ID="example" , wrapper id="example_wrapper".

Here's enough  code will likely get you well on your way. There are easy ways to only update rows but since request is for a complete table reload I've followed that

```
function initDataTables(){
    $('#myTable').datatables({/* put all current options here*/})

}


/* within ready event of pageload */

$(function(){
    initDataTables();
    /* all other page load code*/

});

/* use $.get to reload table */

$.get( tableUpdateUrl, data, function( returnData){

    $('#myTable').parent().replaceWith(returnData);

    /* re-initalize plugin*/

    initDataTables();
});
```

Comment: This is a lot of additional load on the page that isn't necessary.  DataTables provides methods to add new rows to the data set.

Comment: "DataTables provides methods to add new rows to the data set" is not the same as a complete reload. If you just call addRows(data), won't you be duplicating data?

Answer (score 5):

When you create your data table, assign the resulting value into a variable:

```
var table = $(".something").dataTable();
```

When you create your new item, presumably via AJAX, make sure to return the properties that your table needs to display.  Then, in your `success` function, you can make use of the `fnAddData` method to add a new row to your table.  This method takes in an array of values, the first one goes in the first column, second in second, and so on:

```
success: function(response){
    table.fnAddData([
        response.id,
        response.name,
        response.description,
    ]);
}
```

You can read more about the `fnAddData` method [here](http://datatables.net/api).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the ajax plugin. http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api